# How Delphi Sydney 10.4 connect to a third-party build-in bluetooth printer with JAR SDK

Tags: java, android, delphi, jar, sample

My project:

My task is it to built an Android/IOS Application that can connect with Bluetooth Printer and print receipt.

My JAR file:

I had download it from the manufacturer website with the filename iminPrinterSDK.jar and the guide provided.

Now I want use it in Delphi but I don't know how I don't know how to start it.

My Question:

How I can import the .jar file into my project and calling the standard function from the .jar file.

Comment: Have you tried readin [Documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Adding_A_Java_Library_to_Your_Application_Using_the_Project_Manager) on this matter?

Comment: ya, i had tried. but just don't know how to start coding with it.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to start coding to make use of JAVA files either since I never needed this. I just know that the possibility for this exists and thus I have made a quick search of Delphi documentation about this topic for you.

Comment: i see. it's ok, hope someone else can help out! anyway, thanks for your comments.